# how can I download a file from a url(not a direct url) in Linux

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to download a file from below url by using wget command.

http://fx.kebhana.com/FER3701D.web?targetMethod=doTxtDownload&regdate=20160602

```
wget http://fx.kebhana.com/FER3701D.web?targetMethod=doTxtDownload&regdate=20160602 -O test.txt
```

when I type this url in browser it creates text data file and downloads it.
I need to do exact same thing in Linux server.

I found someone asked the same question.
I tried all the solutions of the comments and answers in here, but couldn't solve the problem.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145946/downloading-files-using-wget

If there is any solution, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotation marks around the URL because of the special characters:

```
wget "http://fx.kebhana.com/FER3701D.web?targetMethod=doTxtDownload&regdate=20160602" -O test.txt
```

Comment: it works. what a simple solution.. thanks. you saved my day :)